# Could not find method android() for arguments [build..] on root project '..' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

The following shows up when I'm tryig to work:

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_9cxkoz5xxe5p8ydg2a1ig2k7b$_run_closure1@7b0f017] on root project 'dangerous-forest-game-android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I have been looking for a solution to my problem, but I found my syntax is too different. Here is the code of my `android()` function :

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
compileSdkVersion 20
  sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you apply the `com.gradle.application` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `android` DSL only in your `app/build.gradle` file and **not** in the `root/build.gradle` file.

Also you **have to apply the android plugin** in the `app/build.gradle` file before using it. Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#module-level).

```
/**
 * The first line in the build configuration applies the Android plugin for
 * Gradle to this build and makes the android block available to specify
 * Android-specific build options.
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

/**
 * The android block is where you configure all your Android-specific
 * build options.
 */

android {
  //.....
}
```